# How to get the value of an annotation parameter for usage in AspectJ?

Tags: java, security, annotations, aspectj, aspect

Consider this method:

```
@Access(rights = GUEST)
public void foo() {
  doSomething();
}
```

This pointcut basically matches if the method has an `@Access` annotation:

```
pointcut check() : 
execution(@Access * *(..));
```

But how can I access the field `rights` of @Access, which stores the particular access level, so that I can work with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use:

```
pointcut check(Access access) : 
execution(@Access * *(..)) && @annotation(access);
```

See [documentation here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html#runtime-type-matching-and-context-exposure).

Comment: Cool! This seems to do it. What's the reason I need both?

Comment: `execution` describes your join point and `@annotation` is a pointcut to collect join point context. You can't collect content without defining join point. So `@annotation` requires `execution` (or `call` or something else).

Comment: Ahh ok. So I need execution, but the argument could be something completely unrelated like a method name, too?

Comment: THere can be a lot of different combinations of join points and context collecting pointcuts. You can collect method arguments, annotations of arguments, `this` or `target` etc. It is better to read documentation carefully. It contains a lot of samples.